# adding exception to the htaccess file to bypass a single URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm a newbie with htaccess file so please bear me with my ignorance.

I'm working on a code-igniter project whereby I require to add exception for a particular URL say : www.domain.com/leaveit/file

Basically I have placed a folder at the root which I need to bypass from the rule written in htaccess file where by index.php is added for every request made.

Any suggestion / link would be highly appreciable as I have searched a lot for the solution but didn't end up with anything concrete to help me out of this issue.

Here's my htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
php_flag output_buffering On
```

Thank in advance for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|leaveit)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Let us know if your problem solves or not.

Comment: Don't have enough "reputation" points to do that but will upvote as I get eligible in future.

Comment: oh okey... no problem.